# Give a space in the orderedlist

Tags: html, css

I've the below orderedlist.

```
<div class="chapter">
    <div class="judge">
        <div class="extract">
            <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="para">
                        <span class="item-num">7b.8</span> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="para">
                        <span class="item-num">7b.8.4.2</span>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="para">
                        <span class="item-num">7b.8.4.3</span>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
                    </div>
                </li></ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here the problem is when i attach my CSS and run, if the `<span class="item-num">` has only one dot(i.e. 4 chars), it is looking fine, if it is having more than one dot, the text after it is getting indented, i want to get all the content to start at a single point(like the table looks). And below is the working fiddle with CSS attached.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mx2hkrh/)

to see the exact problem please stretch the output pane in fiddle, till there is no horizontal scrollbar.

Thanks

Comment: How many dots max it can have? You can use a min-width for the `span.item-num`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving width to span:

CSS:

```
.orderedlist li.item div.para span.item-num {
    margin-left: -4.5em; //modified
    padding-right: 1em;
    text-indent: 0em;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    width:50px;//added
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/4mx2hkrh/1/